# Use async with tornado and motor

Tags: python, mongodb, asynchronous, tornado, tornado-motor

Newbie to Python 3.5 and the new `async` and `await` features

The following code only returns a future object. How do I get the actual book item from database and write it to json? And what is the best practice for using async await along with motor-tornado?

```python
async def get(self, book_id=None):
    if book_id:
        book = await self.get_book(book_id)
        self.write(json_util.dumps(book.result()))
    else:
        self.write("Need a book id")

async def get_book(self, book_id):
    book = self.db.books.find_one({"_id":ObjectId(book_id)})
    return book
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for "result()". Since your "get" method is a native coroutine (it's defined with "async def"), then using it with "await" means that a result is already returned to you:

```
async def get(self, book_id=None):
    if book_id:
        # Correct: "await" resolves the Future.
        book = await self.get_book(book_id)
        # No resolve(): "book" is already resolved to a dict.
        self.write(json_util.dumps(book))
    else:
        self.write("Need a book id")
```

However you must also "await" the future in "get_book" in order to resolve it before returning:

```
async def get_book(self, book_id):
    book = await self.db.books.find_one({"_id":ObjectId(book_id)})
    return book
```

Comment: Hi Davis. I tried the above code but got error: `Object of type 'Future' is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Oh, I missed a step in get_book. I've updated my answer.